# XML Not Parsing in Python 2.7 with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, rest

I have the following XML file which I get from REST API

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <boxes>
>   <home id="1" name="productname"/>
>   <server>111.111.111.111</server>
>   <approved>yes</approved>
>   <creation>2007 handmade</creation>
>   <description>E-Commerce, buying and selling both attested</description>
>   <boxtype>
>       <sizes>large, medium, small</sizes>
>       <vendor>Some Organization</vendor>
>       <version>ANY</version>
>   </boxtype>
>   <method>Handmade, Handcrafted</method>
>   <time>2014</time>
> </boxes>
> ```

I am able to get the above output, store in a string variable and print in console,

but when I send this to xml ElementTree

```
import base64
import urllib2
from xml.dom.minidom import Node, Document, parseString
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import XML, fromstring, tostring

print outputxml ##Printing xml correctly,  outputxml contains xml above
content = ET.fromstring(outputxml)
boxes = content.find('boxes')
print boxes
boxtype = boxes.find("boxes/boxtype")
```

If I print the boxes it is giving me `None` and hence is giving me below error

```
boxtype = boxes.find("boxes/boxtype")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: I'm surprised you don't get a parse error -- `<method>Handmade, Handcrafted</discoverMethod>` is clearly broken!

Comment: For a start, the line `  <method>Handmade, Handcrafted</discoverMethod>` is invalid.

Comment: Sorry about that, editing mistake, corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root level node is `boxes`, and it cannot find `boxes` within itself.

```
boxtype = content.find("boxtype")
```

should be sufficient.

DEMO:

```
>>> import base64
>>> import urllib2
>>> from xml.dom.minidom import Node, Document, parseString
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> from xml.etree.ElementTree import XML, fromstring, tostring
>>> 
>>> print outputxml ##Printing xml correctly,  outputxml contains xml above
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<boxes>
  <home id="1" name="productname"/>
  <server>111.111.111.111</server>
  <approved>yes</approved>
  <creation>2007 handmade</creation>
  <description>E-Commerce, buying and selling both attested</description>
  <boxtype>
      <sizes>large, medium, small</sizes>
      <vendor>Some Organization</vendor>
      <version>ANY</version>
  </boxtype>
  <method>Handmade, Handcrafted</method>
  <time>2014</time>
</boxes>
>>> content = ET.fromstring(outputxml)
>>> boxes = content.find('boxes')
>>> print boxes
None
>>> 
>>> boxes
>>> content #note that the content is the root level node - boxes
<Element 'boxes' at 0x1075a9250> 
>>> content.find('boxtype')
<Element 'boxtype' at 0x1075a93d0>
>>>
```

Comment: sure, either ways, the issue is - as in the answer.. the content is the `boxes` element you are looking for.